# SSSD and sudo-rules in Active Directory

Tags: sudo, active-directory

## Note

While making this post I managed to find the problem myself so I thought I might as well post in case it may help someone else later on.
The problem was that I had a typo in **/etc/nsswitch.conf**, I had written **suduers** and not **sudoers**

The **sudoers:** entry wasn't there from the beginning so I had to add it, hence the typo.
One more thing was that the package **libsss-sudo** wasn't installed either, which was needed.

## Post

I have my Linux-servers joined to my AD with SSSD like this:

```
apt-get install sssd-ad sssd-tools realmd adcli krb5-user libsss-sudo
realm join -U Administrator domain.local
```

I can logon with my AD-users just fine but now I want to manage the sudo-rules in AD too.

I extended the AD scheme like this on my AD-server:

```
> wget https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/main/docs/schema.ActiveDirectory -o schema.ActiveDirectory
```

I changed all the **DC=X** entries with **DC=domain,DC=local** and then ran:

```
> ldifde -i -f schema.ActiveDirectory
```

So far so good.
I created a OU where I want all my sudo-rules:

```
OU=Sudo-rules,OU=Linux Servers,OU=Computers,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=local
```

In the OU **Sudo-rules** I created an object with the **sudoRole** class, named it **LinuxAdminsSudo** and edited the following attributes:

```
sudoCommand: ALL
sudoHost: ALL
sudoRunAs: ALL
sudoUser: %linuxadmins@domain.local
```

The **linuxadmins@domain.local** is an AD-group where all the Linux-admins are members and I want them to get full sudo-access to all Linux-servers.

This is my **/etc/sssd/sssd.conf**:

```
[sssd]
domains = domain.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo

[domain/domain.local]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
ad_domain = domain.local
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
sudo_provider = ad

[sudo]
```

In **/etc/nsswitch.conf** I added:

```
sudoers:        sss files
```

Clear cache for SSSD and restart:

```
sss_cache -E
systemctl restart sssd
```

Now I login with a user that's in the **LinuxAdmins**-group and when I run **sudo -l** I get this:

```
Sorry, user admin-user@domain.local may not run sudo on linux-host1.
```

So I'm not allowed to run sudo at all even though the rule in AD should allow this.

When checking the SSSD cache I can see that it has indeed retrieved the rule:

```
ldbsearch -H /var/lib/sss/db/cache_domain.local.ldb
```

I found this entry:

```
# record 28
dn: name=LinuxAdminsSudo,cn=sudorules,cn=custom,cn=domain.local,cn=sysdb
cn: LinuxAdminsSudo
dataExpireTimestamp: 1699953662
entryUSN: 65897179
name: LinuxAdminsSudo
objectCategory: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local
objectClass: sudoRule
originalDN: CN=LinuxAdminsSudo,OU=Sudo-rules,OU=Linux Servers,OU=Computers,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=local
sudoCommand: ALL
sudoHost: ALL
sudoRunAs: ALL
sudoUser: %linuxadmins@domain.local
distinguishedName: name=LinuxAdminsSudo,cn=sudorules,cn=custom,cn=domain.local,cn=sysdb
```

Which indicates that it can retrieve the rule just fine from AD.

And everything was just fine, I had just made a typo in **/etc/nsswitch.conf** stated in the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo in **/etc/nsswitch.conf**
Had written **suduers** and not **sudoers**